# Parsing JSON file using jq,convert it to CSV - combine 2 columns into one

Tags: json, bash, jq

JSON file:https://1drv.ms/u/s!AizscpxS0QM4hJl_VRQaWbm6D8T8_w

Part of file:

```
"RoleDetailList": [
        {
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17", 
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML", 
                        "Effect": "Allow", 
                        "Condition": {
                            "StringEquals": {
                                "SAML:aud": "https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"
                            }
                        }, 
                        "Principal": {
                            "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/CompanyADFS"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            "RoleId": "AROAJANL3L2IZ6UISEGAU", 
            "CreateDate": "2016-08-20T13:51:07Z", 
            "InstanceProfileList": [], 
            "RoleName": "ADFS-Administrators", 
            "Path": "/", 
            "AttachedManagedPolicies": [], 
            "RolePolicyList": [
                {
                    "PolicyName": "Administrator-Access", 
                    "PolicyDocument": {
                        "Version": "2012-10-17", 
                        "Statement": [
                            {
                                "Action": "*", 
                                "Resource": "*", 
                                "Effect": "Allow", 
                                "Sid": "Stmt1434192117145"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ], 
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::279052847476:role/ADFS-Administrators"
        },
```

In other sections `"AttachedManagedPolicies": [],` is not empty it has following structure:

```
"AttachedManagedPolicies": [
                {
                    "PolicyName": "pol-amtest-ro", 
                    "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::279052847476:policy/pol-amtest-ro"
                }
            ]
```

I got all needed columns, just need to combine 2nd and 3rd into single one:

```
jq -rc '.RoleDetailList
| map(select((.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement | length > 0) and 
      (.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.Federated) or 
      (.AttachedManagedPolicies | length >0) or
      (.RolePolicyList | length > 0)) )[]  
| [.RoleName,
   .RolePolicyList[].PolicyName,
   ([.AttachedManagedPolicies[].PolicyName] | join("::")),
   (.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[] | .Principal.Federated)]
| @csv' output.json
```

Output:

```
"ADFS-Administrators","Administrator-Access","","arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/CompanyDFS"
```

How to get rid of `"","` (get it only in first line) ?

Tried `(.RolePolicyList[].PolicyName + " " + .AttachedManagedPolicies[].PolicyName)`

but then getting `"ADFS-Administrators","arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/CompanyADFS"`

Lost values of 2 and 3rd column entirely

Answer (score 0):

needed to wrap it into array and to apply join

```
jq -rc '.RoleDetailList
| map(select((.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement | length > 0) and 
    (.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.Federated) or 
    (.AttachedManagedPolicies | length >0) or 
    (.RolePolicyList | length > 0)) )[]
| [.RoleName,
   ([.RolePolicyList[].PolicyName,
     ([.AttachedManagedPolicies[].PolicyName] | join("--"))] 
    | join(" ")),
   (.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[] | .Principal.Federated)] 
| @csv' output.json
```